# Do travelers entering South Africa from Zambia need a Yellow Fever Certificate?

Tags: health, south-africa, zambia

Zambia was known to have a risk of yellow fever but I understand that currently [it has been declared yellow fever free](http://www.zambiatourism.com/zambias-yellow-fever-free-status-good-for-tourism-in-2015).

What I would like to know is if South Africa needs the Yellow Fever Certificate or not when travelers entering SA are coming(not limited to transit) from Zambia. This [report](http://www.southafrica.info/travel/documents/travel-yellowfever-040215.htm) from Feruary says that it is no longer needed but the CDC website [doesn't say](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/yellowbook/2014/chapter-3-infectious-diseases-related-to-travel/travel-vaccines-and-malaria-information-by-country/south-africa#seldyfm533) any such thing and was last updated in 2014, hence the question.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Great. That had confused me earlier but now it's clear. Thanks much @pnuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the article you linked and WHO documents, if you are entering South Africa through Zambia, Yellow Fever vaccination isn't required anymore.

According to WHO 2015, Zambia is not considered a country with risk of infection. You can see the changed requirements from South African immigration here (search for South Africa): 2013 where [Zambia was mentioned as requiring vaccination](http://www.who.int/ith/ITH_country_list.pdf) and [2015 where Zambia is now omitted](http://www.who.int/ith/2015-ith-county-list.pdf?ua=1) in line with new WHO assessment.

You mentioned "not limited to" transit from Zambia. Make sure your other transit countries are not listed as at risk by the WHO (check out this map for countries with solid red)

[image: WHO Yellow Fever Vaccination Recommendations 2015]

or the WHO 2015 list) or ensure your transit is limited to the airport for less to 12 hours (c.f. South Africa section).

who.int/ith/2015-ith-annex1.pdf?ua=1

(Sorry don't have reputation points to include more than 2 links...)

You could double check by contacting the South Africa Dept of Health - switchboard: 012 395 8000